# laravel - can not change base URL in Docker + Laravel PHP + Nginx

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx, laravel-5

I trying to migrate my backend website (containing API service to mobile apps) from LAMP into docker platform. currently this docker split into 3 parts (Laravel App, database & nginx). sofar, the website launch successfully without error.

However, I need the base URL to be like the below:

**http://backend.example.com/public/**

so, if I want to login, URL will be `http://backend.example.com/public/login`, also API URL with above format like `http://backend.example.com/public/api/v1`

**What I have tried:**

1. Set `APP_URL` value in `.env` to `http://backend.example.com/public/`
2. Set below setting in `config/app.php` to:

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'https://backend.example.com/public'),
'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL', null)
```

3. run `php artisan route:clear` and `php artisan migrate`

but still **not successful**, everytime I launch web browser, URL still **stuck** to:

`http://backend.example.com/`

`http://backend.example.com/login/`

`http://backend.example.com/api/v1/`

etc

any idea to overcome above problem?

===Additional Note

1. **nginx conf** for nginx docker:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/public;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

2. original base URL in LAMP are `http://backend.example.com/public/`, in original i'm using LAMP (Apache+PHP+MySQL) but in current Docker I'm using (Nginx + MySQL + php:7.4-fpm), however because an error, i change something so original base url cannot be achieved anymore...
3. Reference of This Migration [can be found here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-containerize-a-laravel-application-for-development-with-docker-compose-on-ubuntu-18-04).
4. `.htaccess` at apache (old) configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Didn't  you try to replace "location /" to "location /public" in nginx config?

Comment: @IliaYatsenko not yet, will be like this: `location /public {` ?

Comment: @IliaYatsenko i just try it, but it sill not working

Comment: Did you use any rewrite rules in your previous apache configuration?

Comment: just curious: why do you want to use `/public` which is specifically not meant to be used as part of the url?

Comment: @Flame because it has there as constant in mobile apps, if not by backend, then i need to update mobile apps flutter written by previouse developer. Updating flutter much more complex because it has not updated by 1 year so depend on so many plugins, there are too many error. Updating to google Play need to update much dependencies where i see much complex as now.

Comment: @user973254 yes, i have update my post

Comment: @zukijuki Try to add this `rewrite !^public /public/$1 last;` nginx rewrite rule to your default location, I converted this rule from your previous apache config, BTW didn't check if it is working, but you should get the idea

Comment: @zukijuki Try to remove ```/public``` from APP_URL just keep the domain and on nginx conf update root directory to include project directory name ```/project_folder_name/public```

Comment: @user973254 I place this rewrite under `location / {` but when i test in browser by `http://backend.example.com/public/login` then it sill not working

Comment: @SuhailKawsara currently in nginx conf, it has this configuration: `root /var/www/public;`

Comment: It won't working without renaming the `public/` in laravel since that's the default webroot. And you want the entire site in the namespace `public`, this will create a conflict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The APP_URL doesn't really have anything to do with setting the base URL for the actual routes, it is only for setting the base URL that the route helpers append to. What you're looking for instead is a route prefix. One thing to note before we get into this code though YOU NEED TO BE SURE YOU ARE ALWAYS USING ROUTE HELPERS TO DEFINE ROUTES, FORM ACTIONS, BASICALLY ANYTHING THAT INTERACTS WITH A URL. Otherwise you will have to remember to add the public to the path everywhere.

Open up your Route Service Provider in app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider

look for the map() function and add the route prefix

```
Route::prefix('public')->group(function () {
        $this->mapApiRoutes();

        $this->mapWebRoutes();
});
```

that's it. Now any route that is mapped by the route service provider will have the public/ prefix applied.

My source for this is just an extrapolation of the documentation for how to add a prefix to any route group https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-group-prefixes